# Передать данные из активности в AlertDialog

Tags: java, android

В активности имеется `int` с каким-то значением, из активности запускается `AlertDialog` фрагментом.

Как в данном диалоге отобразить данную переменную?

Диалог:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;


public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

int right = 0;
int wrong = 0;

@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("title")
            .setMessage("msg " + toString().valueOf(right) + " || " + toString().valueOf(wrong))
            .setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setPositiveButton("Bullshit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Фрагмент кода активности:

```
public void onAnsw3Click(View view) {
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAnsw3);
    String myText = button.getText().toString();
    int tr = myText.indexOf(tempRight);
    if (tr == 0) {
        scoreRight++;
    } else {
        scoreWrong++;
    }
    createField();
}

public void endGame() {
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    MyDialogFragment myDialogFragment = new MyDialogFragment();
    myDialogFragment.show(manager, "dialog");
}
```

Соответственно, передать нужно `scoreRight` и `scoreWrong` и использовать их в диалоге на месте `right` и `wrong`.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Добавьте код первого и второго.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Я так и продолжил бы в сторону Extras копать, так и не раскопал бы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Передать данные во фрагмент (при его создании) можно с помощью аргументов фрагмента:

В `MyDialogFragment` добавляете **статический** метод `newInstance(...)`:

```
public static MyDialogFragment newInstance(int right, int wrong) {
    MyDialogFragment fragment = new MyDialogFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("right", right);
    args.putInt("wrong", wrong);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

и переопределяете метод `onCreate(...)`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    right = getArguments().getInt("right");
    wrong = getArguments().getInt("wrong");
}
```

В `activity` создаете инстанс фрагмента с помощью метода `newInstance(...)`:

```
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
MyDialogFragment myDialogFragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance(scoreRight, scoreWrong);
myDialogFragment.show(manager, "dialog");
```